# how to get last inserted record ID within web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, web

am trying to get the inserted record id from a web service after the web method do the insert 
but its came without id even the insertion going well 
so how could i got that id within the web service if we know that the insertion method return bool 
by the way its return the id in the web service but when i go to my application it still null

```
 if (ExecuteSqlCommand(Comm) > 0)
        {
            result = true;
            Obj.CUSTOMER_BANK_ACC_ID = (decimal)Comm.Parameters["p_CUSTOMER_BANK_ACC_ID"].Value;
        }
        return result;
```

Comment: If the web service has the ID, it needs to pass it back as part of payload from the web service call. Sounds like the web service is not doing that.

Comment: why i couldn't return the id in the passed object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it guys 
if you want to return the inserted record id within the web service impeded in the passed object 
just pass the object by ref and here  the code

**web service function**

```
  public bool AddObject(ref T_COMN_CUSTOMER_BANK_ACC_Entity Obj)
    {
        bool result = false;
        OracleCommand Comm = new OracleCommand(InsertCommandName, Connection);
        Comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Comm.Parameters.Add("p_CUSTOMER_ID", OracleType.Number).Value = Obj.CUSTOMER_ID;
        Comm.Parameters.Add("p_CUSTOMER_TP_ID", OracleType.Number).Value = Obj.CUSTOMER_TP_ID;
        Comm.Parameters.Add("p_CUSTOMER_BANK_ACC_ID", OracleType.Number).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        Comm.Parameters.Add("p_BANK_ID", OracleType.Number).Value = Obj.BANK_ID;
        Comm.Parameters.Add("p_IBAN", OracleType.NVarChar, 200).Value = Obj.IBAN;
        Comm.Parameters.Add("p_IS_DELETED", OracleType.Number).Value = Obj.IS_DELETED;
        Comm.Parameters.Add("p_CREATED_BY", OracleType.NVarChar, 200).Value = Obj.CREATED_BY;
        Comm.Parameters.Add("p_CREATED_DT", OracleType.DateTime).Value = Obj.CREATED_DT;
        Comm.Parameters.Add("p_MODIFIED_BY", OracleType.NVarChar, 200).Value = Obj.MODIFIED_BY;
        Comm.Parameters.Add("p_MODIFIED_DT", OracleType.DateTime).Value = Obj.MODIFIED_DT;
        if (ExecuteSqlCommand(Comm) > 0)
        {
            result = true;
            Obj.CUSTOMER_BANK_ACC_ID = (decimal)Comm.Parameters["p_CUSTOMER_BANK_ACC_ID"].Value;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and i called it in the web application like that

```
pers.AddObject(ref Customer_Bank_Acc_Obj);
```